# SeekBar - Can't set starting point

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, android-seekbar

When I first start my app, before the Shared Preferences are created, I want my seekbar to be set on 300px (max 600). It seems simple, as all I need to do is use setProgress and give it a value of 300. But for some reason this is not working in my code, and whatever I do, the starting point remains at 0. I was wondering if you had any idea what I am doing wrong. Many thanks.

```
    public void sizeButton(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.size_btn) {
        seekDialog = new Dialog(this);
        seekDialog.setContentView(R.layout.size_chooser);
        seekTxt = (TextView) seekDialog.findViewById(R.id.spq_txt);
        seekSpq = (SeekBar) seekDialog.findViewById(R.id.size_seek);
        seekSpq.setMax(600);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(LauncherPage.PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (prefs != null) {
            int currSize = prefs.getInt("size", size);
            seekSpq.setProgress(currSize);
            seekTxt.setText(Integer.toString(currSize) + " pixels");
        } else {
            seekSpq.setProgress(300);
        }
    }
```

To be clear "seekSpq.setProgress(currSize);" works just fine. The one that doesn't work is "seekSpq.setProgress(300);".

Comment: your else part on checking prefs object will wont fire. prefs object seems to be always not a null object.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas where I should set the starting progress in that case?

Comment: seekSpq.setProgress( prefs.getInt("size", 300));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(LauncherPage.PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
int currSize = prefs.getInt("size", size);
if (currSize !=0) {
    seekSpq.setProgress(currSize);
    seekTxt.setText(Integer.toString(currSize) + " pixels");
}else{
    seekSpq.setProgress(300);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent hours on this!:)

Comment: quick question. If a user selects size 0, progress is shown as 300. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Ok, the answer was to use: if (prefs.contains("size"))... This way, 0 does not show as 300.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `SharedPreferences` can be `null`. So I wouldn't use that as the condition and instead use your `size`. Like so:

```
if (prefs.getInt("size", size) != null) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too in a different way I found out the order in which we setProgress is important for example the following did not work in setting the progress bar:

```
seekBar.setProgress(160);  
seekBar.setMax(250);
seekBar.setMin(120);
```

but the following worked:

```
 seekBar.setMax(250);
 seekBar.setMin(120);
 seekBar.setProgress(160);
```